# AVAudio player singleton crashes on a isPlaying check

Tags: ios, singleton, avaudioplayer

I am using a singleton for AVAudioPlayer, it works great.

I wish to add a check before initializing the player and stop the player if it already playing something.

I added this code :

```
SoundPlayer *player = [SoundPlayer sharedInstance];
        if([player isPlaying]){
            [player stop];
 }
```

But it gives me a EXE_BAD_ACCESS on the `if([player isPlaying])` line.

2 Questions:

1. If this is a singleton and I am getting back the same player then why doesn't it stopes by itself?
2. Why am I getting the error?

**HERE IS THE FULL CODE**

```
    #import "SoundPlayer.h"

    @implementation SoundPlayer
    @synthesize helpMode;

    static SoundPlayer *sharedInstance = nil;

    + (SoundPlayer *)sharedInstance {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }

        return sharedInstance;
    }


    +(BOOL)playSound:(NSURL*)url{

       NSError *error;
        SoundPlayer *player = [SoundPlayer sharedInstance];
            if([player isPlaying]){
                [player stop];
            }

       player = [[SoundPlayer sharedInstance] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
       [player play];

        if (player == nil){
            NSLog(@"error %@ \n for file %@",[error description],[url path]);   
            return NO;
        }else {
            if (![player helpMode]) {
                 [player play];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"help mode");
            }

        }
         return YES;
    }

    -(void)stopSound{
        if ([self isPlaying]) {
            [self stop];
        }
    }


    @end
```

Comment: what is SoundPlayer's super class?  Where is the isPlaying, stop, play and helpMode methods?  Why are you creating another pointer to your singleton within your singleton instead of just using self?

Comment: Hey. The super class is AVAoudioPlayer. Do I have to override all the methods? Please explain your other questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if this is whats causing the error, but figured I would post my response to the discussion here to make my point clearer since Ill have more room and code formatting.

No you dont have to override all the methods, i was just asking to make sure I understood everything right. 
The other piece of what im saying is that just like in `stopSound{}`, you should be using self not

`SoundPlayer *player = [SoundPlayer sharedInstance];`

so change your code to this, run it and see if its fixed, post a comment below to let me know the outcome.

```
 -(BOOL)playSound:(NSURL*)url{

       NSError *error;
       // SoundPlayer *player = [SoundPlayer sharedInstance];
            if([self isPlaying]){
                [self stop];
            }

       //not sure if this should be self or super (i think super, try both)
       //if you overrided the init then definitely self

       //[self initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
       [super initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];


       [self play];

        if (self == nil){
            NSLog(@"error %@ \n for file %@",[error description],[url path]);   
            return NO;
        }else {
            if (![self helpMode]) {
                 [self play];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"help mode");
            }

        }
         return YES;
    }
```

Really all your doing is creating a pointer to self with you create a player object since it is a singleton.  With that said Im not sure why that would make it crash other then the fact that you "should" be using self instead.

---

```
+ (SoundPlayer *)sharedInstance {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }

        return sharedInstance;
    }
```

see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) that AVAudioPlayer only has 2 `init` methods and neither are just `init` hence you are not completely initializing your super class.  You need to override `initWithContentsOfURL:url` method and initialize this object and its super with the url parameter.  Just make sure you put the `initWithContentsOfURL:url` in both the .h and .m.  Also idk if it matters but try just `alloc` not `allocWithZone`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. I changed all the code to self (BTW ha to convert the method from class method to instance method) still crashing. BTW if I check 'self' I get an object and not nil.